# Location where Eclipse stores the path to android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, windows

I'd like to script the setting of the android SDK location in Eclipse Neon on windows and need to know what file it stores the path in.

I've found the following two locations, but neither seem to work:

%userprofile%\.android\ddms.cfg

and

workspace\.metadata.plugins\org\eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.andmore.prefs

Comment: Eclipse doesn't store the SDK, it is installed onto your system. For example, Macs may store it somewhere like `~/Library/Android/sdk/`

Comment: I understand it doesn't store it, but it does store the _location_ of the sdk.

Comment: Ohhhh I misread a bit of it and it makes _way_ more sense now

Answer (score 1):

Correct path:

```
workspace\.metadata.plugins\org\eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs
```

You'll find the following property for SDK path

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk
```

Comment: There should be a location outside the workspace, as a fresh install with an old workspace still prompts for the sdk location.